# Got error when install curl 7.66.0-r0 in alpine: "curl_multi_poll: symbol not found"

Tags: curl, alpine-linux

Recently, curl was released its new version 7.66.0. When my curl in alpine was upgraded to this version. I always got the error below when I run curl with any URL.

**curl_multi_poll: symbol not found**

It was working fine with previous version 7.65.3. Do I need to upgrade some other libs or something else to make it work?

Comment: It seems like I need to run `apk upgrade` to upgrade curl's dependencies(e.g. libcurl) after running `apk add curl`. That would upgrade curl's dependencies to latest version. The "curl-multi_pool" comes from the latest version of libcurl

Answer (score 5):

You should do instead of `apk --upgrade --no-cache add curl` which upgrade only the one we are dealing issues with, instead of `apk upgrade` which will upgrade all of packages and could lead us to indesirable behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will git it a try.